# NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter when compiling maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have recently started my first maven project and after creating a file which uses spring security it doesn't launch anymore due to "ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter".

I have been googling for past 2 hours, but I am yet not efficient enough with projects like that to troubleshoot it properly. I was mainly tinkering with the pom.xml file (which is most likely the problem).

pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.freshvotes</groupId>
    <artifactId>freshvotes</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>freshvotes</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
     <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
 </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

WebSecurityConfig file which caused the problem:

```
package com.freshvotes.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("qwerty@yahoo.com")
            .password("qwerty")
            .roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

Console:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$SecurityFilterChainConfiguration
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:470) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:131) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:428) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:349) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:775) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:597) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:753) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:455) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1342) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1331) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at com.freshvotes.FreshvotesApplication.main(FreshvotesApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2a139a55]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:483) ~[spring-core-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:360) ~[spring-core-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:417) ~[spring-core-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$1(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:751) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:750) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:683) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:654) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1636) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:532) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:247) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:240) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:230) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:183) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:158) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberOutcomes.getConditionOutcome(AbstractNestedCondition.java:195) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberOutcomes.<init>(AbstractNestedCondition.java:189) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberConditions.lambda$getMatchOutcomes$0(AbstractNestedCondition.java:169) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:729) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.util.MultiValueMapAdapter.forEach(MultiValueMapAdapter.java:179) ~[spring-core-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.forEach(Collections.java:1553) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberConditions.getMatchOutcomes(AbstractNestedCondition.java:169) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberMatchOutcomes.<init>(AbstractNestedCondition.java:78) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition.getMatchOutcome(AbstractNestedCondition.java:63) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3458) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2557) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:465) ~[spring-core-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
        ... 49 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You shouldn't manage versions of `org.springframework.security:spring-security-config` yourself, but let Spring Boot manage it. Spring Boot 3.2.0 requires version 6.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem that you have here is in mixing of framework versions

To fix it you have to remove

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And also be sure that you replace all projects imports from `javax.x` to `jakarta.x`.
Because from Spring Boot 3.x and Spring Framework 6.x all `javax.` were replaced with `jakarta.x`.

Also you will have to migrate Spring Security Configuration part because how I see you are using a lot of deprecated and removed parts of Spring Framework.

More details you can find in next ones resources.
[Spring Boot 3.0 Migration](https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0)

[Spring Security without the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter)

[Migration Guide Spring Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html)

Comment: The reason why I'm writing it like that is because I'm learning it from very accesible course which has a couple of years now. Was hoping that it would be possible to make it work like that. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Removing the `<version>` tag would also be sufficient, though I guess (not in the mood to doublecheck) it is also imported by `spring-boot-starter-security`.

Comment: @ShekelSniffer if it help you could accept it for future if someone else will have the same problem as you.

Comment: @AndreiLisa was planning to do that but thanks for reminding me! Still new to the platform.